How to use a list comprehension to verify something in one list and add from another?
I have a list of characters and a list of yes and no.
list1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
list2 = ["Yes", "No", "Yes"]

I'd like to do something like:
i = 0
for x in list1:
   if list2[i] == "Yes":
      list3.append(list1[i]) 
      i += 1

But with list comprehension or at least some easier and shorter way to do this.
So that it goes from
list1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
list2 = ["Yes", "No", "Yes"]
list3 = []

To
list3 = ["A", "C"]


Related: How do I iterate through two lists in parallel?

Zip up the two lists to generate pairs (x, cond), then check if "Yes":
list3 = [
    x
    for x, cond in zip(list1, list2)
    if cond == "Yes"
]

Since len(list3) ≤ len(list2), this is a good indicator that we need an if after the for.

You can filter List1 using values from List2:
List1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
List2 = ["Yes", "No", "Yes"]
List3 = [value for i, value in enumerate(List1) if List2[i] == "Yes"]
print(List3)


zip is definitely the better way to do this. Even if you wanted it to error out when the list lengths don't match, passing zip strict=True will get you an error, without the issues with indexing (poor names, IndexErrors, worse performance, etc.). enumerate is the better solution when you're using the index to reassign elements of the source list, or you actually need to number the values for non-indexing reasons, but zip is the way to go when iterating multiple iterators in parallel.

@ShadowRanger in terms of flexibility with different length of tables enumerate is better as you can decide in condition what you should do in case if index is in List1 and not exist in List2.  Apart from this case, zip looks like better solution.
